# How to obtain full value inside jQuery's keypress event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, jquery-events

I'm writing some jQuery which intercepts the value entered in an input field and determines whether to allow or to prevent the typed value.

I need to get the next value, *i.e.*, what the value will be were I to permit the key-press, and I need to know this value at a point before it is displayed, so I'm using the `keypress` event.

My question is: inside the `keypress` event, how can I tell what the resultant value would be were I to permit the key-press? What is the '*potential value*'?

If I write out the key-press event object to the console and inspect the properties, I can see that `currentTarget.value` shows this 'potential value'. However, if I use this property inside the `keypress` event then it returns only the value prior to the context key-press.

For example, if the user types "a" into an empty text box bound to the following jQuery

```
$(":input").on("keypress", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
});
```

Digging down through the first console output (`e`) shows that `currentTarget.value` = "a".

But the second console output (`e.currentTarget.value`) will show "".

If the user was then to type "b" into that same text box then:
Manually inspectng `e` and locating `currentTarget.value` displays "ab"; Dumping `e.currentTarget.value` from inside the event displays "a".

Can anyone explain how I can get this '*potential value*' while inside the `keypress` event?

Comment: `this.value + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode)`

Comment: That assumes that the latest addition has been appended. What if the user uses the arrow keys or clicks into the middle of a string and then enters a character? What if the user was to delete a character from any position in the text field?

Comment: That's why it is a comment and not an answer. There are obviously more cases to handle.

Comment: This is hard to do. A text can be changed via mouse-only manipulations (drag, copy, paste, cut, delete), and several keys have specials effects, such as `Del`, `BS`, `Ctrl+X`, `Ctrl+V`, `Shft+Del`, `Shft+INS`, ... to deal with all those case you might end up with quite a large piece of code that tries to mimic what the browser will do when processing the events.

Comment: I think it is more user friendly to let the user act with a text box as they expect. You don't want them to think one of their keys on their keyboard is broke. In my opinion it is better to give a visual indication that the current content is or is not valid without blocking the standard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the prettiest of solutions (you can see the would be result just before it's reverted), but to save the trouble of discerning between arrow/control and input keys etc, you could store the original value in `keypress` and revert to that in `keyup` if needed (also storing the selection positions for complete reversion)

```
$(":input").keypress(function(e) {
    $(this).data('orgValue', {value: this.value, pos: this.selectionStart, selend:this.selectionEnd});
}).keyup(function(e){
    var val = this.value;
    if(!somevalidation(val)){
        var org =$(this).data('orgValue');        
        this.value = org.value;
        this.selectionStart = org.pos;
        this.selectionEnd = org.selend;
    }
});
```

Example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9986zs4j/)

**Edit**

Did some testing, but jquery makes predicting the outcome relatively easy. Not only does it fill the key property, it also fills other properties on its event on which the type of key can be checked. While testing charCode seems to be 0 for 'non input' keys.
The straight forward would be:

```
$(":input").keypress(function(e) {
    if(!e.charCode)return; //is 0 for non input
    var cur = this.value; //current value
    var val = cur.substring(0,this.selectionStart)
        + e.key
        + cur.substring(this.selectionEnd);     
    return cur=== val //unchanged
        || somevalidation(val);        
});
```

But that would not include deletes/backspaces, to handle those as well:

```
$(":input").keypress(function(e) {
    var key,start = this.selectionStart ,end = this.selectionEnd;
    if(e.charCode)
        key = e.key;
    else{
        if(e.keyCode===8 || e.keyCode===46){
            key = '';
            if(end===start){
                if(e.keyCode===8)
                    start--;
                else
                    end++;
            }
        }
        else
            return true; //charCode is 0 for non input 46 = delete 8 = backspace
    }
    var cur = this.value; //current value
    var val = cur.substring(0, start) + key + cur.substring(end);     
    return cur=== val //unchanged
        || somevalidation(val);        
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9986zs4j/3/)

While testing this seemed to behave as expected. An other way might be have a hidden input field, send the keys there and examine its results, but the above should do the trick.

Comment: I like the approach. Anything you could improve to take care of multiple `keypress` events before `keyup` occurs? There is also a slight negative side-effect in that the undo sequence will be distorted, but I agree this is far better than trying to predict the final result and cancel `keypress` if validation fails.

Comment: It's a valid answer and I appreciate the effort (so +1), but the temporary visibility of the pressed key is undesirable.

Comment: Gotcha, thought perhaps it was user friendly if it could be seen that something was happening but not allowed. @trincot has a good point about the undo sequence too. Anyway, took another look and added a version with preventing the keypress.

Comment: With this method you need to also treat key combinations that do clipboard actions, like Ctrl+X, Shift+Del, Ctrl+V, Shift+Ins, ... and what was not mentioned yet, there are text manipulations possible with select + mouse drag. Also pasting can happen with mouse only.

Comment: Very true I'm afraid. Guess the 2 approaches could be combined into something like http://jsfiddle.net/9986zs4j/4/ ,at least it also handles pastes and such, but that still doesn't feel quite right. For mouse dragging and such validation can be handled in the change event. But in that scope a custom control seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Me.Name: You are on your way in writing such custom control :-)

Comment: As well as the actions that @trincot mentions, there are also arrow keys to consider: the user could move to and fro through the field's current string, tapping other keys as they go. Things would be much simpler if jQuery just exposed the complete string.

Comment: @awj, Me.Name took care of arrow keys, selections being made in the mddle, etc, that is not a problem. Also, it should certainly not be jQuery who should *just* expose the complete string. If anyone, it is the browser that should do this, as it is the browser that actually "calculates" the total effect of the user input.